# VB.NET MYSQL Displaying Data using MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hello I'm trying to display data in vb.net using MySQL syntax here is my Mysql syntax

```
SELECT  COUNT(status) as 'Number of Grade School for the Month of January'
                                    FROM blhtraining.userinfo
                                    Where survey_at='Talisay' 
                                    and status='College' and Month(member_since)='1' and 
                                    Year(member_since)='2021'
```

And this code works in Mysql but when i modify it like this in vb.net

```
 Dim count_gradeSchool1 As String = "Select Case COUNT(status) As 'Members'
                                            From training.userinfo
                                            Where survey_at='" & txtmonthlylocation.Text & "' 
                                            And status ='College' 
                                            And Month(member_since)='" & monthly_reports & "'  
                                            And YEAR(member_since)='" & txtmyear.Text & "' 
                                            And Day(member_since)='11'"



        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(count_gradeSchool1, mycon)
        dt = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        lblgs1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Members")
```

I recieved this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'As 'Members'
> From training.u' at line 1

I'm sure the syntax is correct is it the variable declared?

Comment: That darn Select Case!! The editor likes to put that in and it doesn't belong. Get rid of Case. Please learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection. Not sure what these date functions in MySql return but I would be very surprised if they were strings. Get rid of the single quotes around the values for the date functions.

Comment: still not working

Comment: its okay na i remove the case thanks

Comment: The error message says that there's an error in the SQL code but you haven't shown us the SQL code, which suggests that you didn't even look at it. The VB that constructs the SQL code not the SQL code itself. Look at the place where you're told the error is.

Comment: Don't use `'` for identifiers. Don't use spaces in column name aliases (if you want to format a column name nicely, do it in the front end, not the back end). Don't concatenate values into SQL statements; concatenate parameters in (if you ever need to concatenate anything) - this SQL is not dynamic enough to need concatted params and can just have hard coded parameters. Don't run functions on columns in a WHERE clause; use a date range and leave the table data alone

Answer (score 0):

Your problems probably came about because you pasted the SQL into your code without starting a string first, so VB saw "select" and helped you out by adding "case". So, here is code that...

- ...has fixed SQL syntax
- ...uses parameters. Always use parameters. You've no idea how many times a day I say this, trying to stem the tide of future SQL injection hacks. Writing code that doesn't use parameters will get you fired, or you'll have to live with the [consequences of writing hack prone code](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack&ia=web) on your conscience. Don't ever skip on using parameters in your SQLs, even if it's "only an app to track your grandma's record collection"
- ...doesn't call functions on columns in the where clause - don't do it; it's a huge waste of resources and kills opportunities to use indexes. Always, always try to leave table data alone, untransformed. In 99% of cases there is another way to write the query
- ...uses executescalar - you only want one value, pointless using an adapter/table for it
- ...doesn't use column alises with spaces in - as noted in the comments - don't do it; it's not the database's job to format your column names, it's the front end's job.

  ```
    Dim count_gradeSchool1 As String = "Select COUNT(*) as c
        FROM training.userinfo
        Where survey_at = @loc 
           And status = 'College'
           And member_since = @ms"

    Using c = New MySqlCommand(count_gradeSchool1, mycon)
      c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", txtmonthlylocation.Text)
      c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ms", new Date(CInt(txtmyear.Text), CInt(monthly_reports), 11)

      c.Connection.Open() 'if it's not already open

      lblgs1.Text = c.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

    End Using
  ```